# File Writing Permission

Tags: c#, file-io, file-permissions

I am writting an app to dump content into files.

The flow, so far is this:

```
1 - User enters a Path

2 - App checks if the Directory Exists and if i have Writting Permissions

 2.a - If if exists, creates a empty file inside and closes it
 2.b - If it does not, creates the directory and the file inside it, and closes the file
```

The problem is, once i reach the point when i actually have to write content in this file i previously created i can't write a single line , it throws me a "Access to Path Denied".

Here is the code snippet related to the issue :

```
        // Writting ImgPixels to file

        if (BDC.BDCCommons.CommonUtils.DirectoryHasWritePermissions(folderPath))
        {
            using (StreamWriter filePointer = File.AppendText(folderPath))
            {
                filePointer.WriteLine(imgPixels);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LogWriter.Error ("Permissão Negada", "Diretorio [ " + folderPath + "] nao tem permissao de escrita");
        }
```

What might be causing this ?!
Thanks in advance Guys

**Improving Question:**

@500 - Internal Server Error : folderPath is the Path to the Folder,yes.

I Guess i see where is my mistake. There is no file to be written, just a folder. My Bad

Comment: Hmm - "folderPath" is that the name of the folder (only) or the entire file name?

Comment: You're calling `File.AppendText()` on the folder?

Comment: Does the error occur on the using statement or the filePointer.WriteLine statement?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Correct, i am passing the folderpath instead of the file path. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
using (StreamWriter filePointer = File.AppendText(folderPath))
```

to

```
using (StreamWriter filePointer = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName)))
```

Comment: It would be better to use `Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName)`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you're trying to write a file, you may need admin rights in order to do so.  I worked on a project where I had to write a file to a subdirectory of the Program Files folder, but ran into the permissions issue.

I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/f6cd003f-ba3b-44f3-817f-2d8b4e11a0eb/) for a solution.  It describes how to edit the manifest file for the project in order to grant access rights for the application on startup.

Comment: It is not a problem, i also wrote my own code to get these permissions when needed, so as the code to check if i have write permissions on a path. Thanks tho , i will give it a read ;D